# How to update the Source Code as well with terraform apply?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform script to deploy an AWS Glue Job with it's sourcecode (ET script). When I run `terraform apply` it's updating the infrastructure. But not the source code. What should I do to update the code as well??

Folder structure.

```
--glue-script-tf.py
--main.tf
```

Below is my terraform script(main.tf).

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-east-1"
}

variable "job-language" {
  default = "python"
}
    
variable "bucket-name" {
  default = "glue-poc"
}

variable "glue-role-arn" {
  default = "arn:aws:iam::#####:role/dp-da-glue-poc-role-dev"
}

variable "job-name" {
  default = "glue-job-from-terraform"
}

variable "file-name" {
  default = "glue-script-tf.py"
}

#===========================================
    
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "upload-glue-script" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket-name}"
  key    = "scripts/${var.file-name}"
  source = "${var.file-name}"
}
    
resource "aws_glue_job" "glue-job" {
  name        = "${var.job-name}"
  role_arn    = "${var.glue-role-arn}"
  description = "This is script to create large files from small files "
  max_retries = "1"
  timeout     = 2880
  command {
    script_location = "s3://${var.bucket-name}/scripts/${var.file-name}"
    python_version = "3"
  }
  execution_property {
    max_concurrent_runs = 2
  }
  glue_version = "4.0"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do (depending on the terraform version you are using) is to use the [`filemd5` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/filemd5) with the [`etag` argument](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_object#etag):

> (Optional) Triggers updates when the value changes. The only meaningful value is `filemd5("path/to/file")` (Terraform 0.11.12 or later) or `${md5(file("path/to/file"))}` (Terraform 0.11.11 or earlier).

So, if you are using newer terraform versions, you could do the following:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "upload-glue-script" {
  bucket = var.bucket-name
  key    = "scripts/${var.file-name}"
  source = var.file-name
  etag   = filemd5("${var.file-name}") # or ${md5(file("${var.file-name}"))}
}
```

Note also that if the file is bigger than 16MB, you should default to using [`source_hash` argument](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_object#source_hash) (it also helps if you enable encryption with SSE-KMS).

Comment: great, that worked. I hope it will work for additional custom python modules as well.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform does not automatically detect the code changes in your **glue-script-tf.py**. It only detects infrastructure changes.

When you run **terraform apply** Terraform will try to determine whether any changes are necessary based on the resources you've defined in your configuration. If you modify the Glue script and then run terraform apply, Terraform might not automatically detect the change and update the Glue Job with the new script.

In summary, whatever you edit in your Python file it will not be taken as infrastructure change and it will show **no changes - your current infrastructure matches the configuration**.

Alternatively, you can use the **file function** to read the Glue script content and upload it to S3. This approach ensures that changes in your python file be detected and take action.

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "upload-glue-script" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket-name}"
  key = "scripts/${var.file-name}"
  content = file("${var.file-name}")
}
```